# Default Realm After Login

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How can I set the default Realm where I am logged in?
Currently I'm in *Malygos*, where I have no characters. The only Realm where I have played is *Alleria*.

I've tried to view the config files with Notepad++ to find where the "default Realm" is *Malygos*, but I didn't find anything.

Facts:

- I'm the Only one on this Computer and Account
- I was recruited (be part *Recruit A Friend*)
- `SET realmName "Alleria"` is in the Config.wtf

Is it possible to set the Default Realm to *Alleria* and not *Malygos* even when the Friend recruited me from Malygos?

Edit: I asked Blizzard and the answer to this is correct. You will be always on the Realm where you where recruited. No one can change that! Not even Blizzard!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My wife has had this problem.

I recruited her from Onyxia, but we play together on Ghostlands--the result is that every time she logs in, it defaults to Onyxia.

According to what I read, the only thing you can do about this is wait. Once your RAF time runs out with whoever recruited you, your realm default can be set to whatever you want. But as long as you are still RAF linked, you're going to default to the realm the person was logged into whenever they recruited you.

Comment: when no right answer will be given in the next days, i mark this as the Answer, if some sources are given ;) It could be the only reason then why this happens.

Answer (score 4):

The default realm is set in the config.wtf file in the WTF folder (C:\Program Files\World of Warcraft\WTF).

You can open the file with WordPad, and edit the following line:

```
SET realmName "Alleria"
```

Comment: Oh sweet didn't know that. Always thought the one with the most characters is your default.

Comment: That wouldn't be in my case ;) i have only 3 characters and they are all on Alleria. I Will try it at home but i think i already done that.

Comment: That's also what I assumed. I have read some things that if you used RAF it automatically set your deafult realm to your friends realm.

Comment: That can be a Reason, but does it mean the Realm what it his default Realm or which he is currently connected?

Comment: @Serverfrog I don't know it for sure, but I assume it's the Realm he was on when you joined.

Comment: I'm sure you would have mentioned this, but do you have more than one account or would anyone else play from your computer? If I play on Al'Akir on my main account and then later switch to my alt account, where I play on Kazzak, upon logging back into my main account, I'll be on Kazzak instead of Al'Akir.

Comment: @Damek Sorry, don't work

Comment: @Lyrical i'm the only one who has access to my computer AND account